# perf report function names and extra characters

Tags: profiling, perf

I have profiled an application using `perf`, and I am confused why the names of the functions are so mangled in the report. For example, here is the output of `perf report`:

```
# Overhead      Command      Shared Object                                                                                                 
# ........  ...........  .................  .................................................................................................................................................................................................
#
    38.98%  hello_sp_tp  libc-2.19.so       [.] __memcpy_sse2_unaligned                                                                                                                                                                      
            |
            --- __memcpy_sse2_unaligned
               |          
               |--21.70%-- _ZN5nupic10algorithms6Cells46CStateaSERKS2_.local.1629
               |          
                --17.28%-- _ZN5nupic10algorithms6Cells46Cells420updateInferenceStateERKSt6vectorIjSaIjEE
                          _ZN5nupic10algorithms6Cells46Cells47computeEPfS3_bb
```

For example, I recognize the name `nupic.algorithms.Cells4.updateInferenceState()`, but I'm not sure what all the other characters that pad the names mean.

What is `_ZN5`? What is `IjSaIjEE` at the end of this function name? What do these mean? Where do they come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These (C++ functions) names are mangled. Look at [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) for the syntax details. That allows to encode complex C++ namings.

About your perf report, there are options to ask for demangling: `--demangle` that is theoretically set by default but real implementation may depend on the perf version or your CPU architecture.

Comment: Yes, I was confused by this because I learned from the perf man page that `--demangle` is set by default, yet I was still seeing name mangling. Are there any options I need to set for GCC to facilitate name demangling?

Comment: @mateja There is nothing to do at the GCC level. Demangling is done by perf. I see no direct visible reason why that could depend on arch but I saw a demangling bug on ARM64. If you really want to demangle without fixing perf, you could write a script to post-process the report, even if not very convenient. The script could call `c++filt` that is a command able to translate, for example `c++filt_ZN5nupic10algorithms6Cells46Cells47computeEPfS3_bb` will give `nupic::algorithms::Cells4::Cells4::compute(float*, float*, bool, bool)`

Answer (score 0):

perf is probably build without support for demangling on your system.

If your system is Ubuntu have a look here: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1396654
and workaround provided here: 
[perf enable demangling of callgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057653/perf-enable-demangling-of-callgraph/34061874#34061874)