# Perf shows mangled function names

Tags: c++, profiling, perf, name-mangling

I wanted to give perf a shot to profile some programs after I saw [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk&feature=youtu.be&list=PLHTh1InhhwT75gykhs7pqcR_uSiG601oh) talk from CppCon 2015. I downloaded the same Google benchmark library that the guy uses in the talk, compiled my program with the appropriate switches, linked it to it, then used perf to record a run. The report option gives me this:

[image]

As you can see the function names are not very readable. I assume this has to do with C++ name mangling. Interestingly, all the function names show up correctly in the video for the guy who gave the talk, but not for me. I don't think it's a case of completely missing the symbol information because I would only see memory addresses in that case. For some reason, perf can't "undo" the C++ name mangling for me, and this is frustrating to look at.

I'm using gcc (g++) version 5.2.1, perf is version 4.2.6, and I use these switches when compiling:

`-I<my own include path> -L<path to the benchmark library> -O3 -std=c++14 -gdwarf-2 -fno-rtti -Wall -pedantic -lbenchmark -pthread`

The reason why I don't use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is that I use the `-gdwarf-2` option instead, which leaves debugging information in the dwarf executable, which is an alternative for leaving the frame pointer in place in this case. This also means I pass `--call-graph "dwarf"` to `perf record`. Anyway, I tried the frame pointer method as well, and it gives the same results, so this doesn't matter really.

So why doesn't perf "undo" the C++ name mangling in this case? Does this have anything to do with using GCC, which of course means that I'm using libstdc++?

Comment: I'm using Arch Linux and `perf report` shows correct symbol demanging.  The man page for perf also shows there is a `--demangle` option that is enabled by default.  Since I'm not seeing the same behavior as you I don't have an answer, but what you are seeing is not expected default behavior.

Comment: I tried adding that switch manually as well, but it didn't change anything

Comment: @GabrielSouthern Are you using gcc as well?

Comment: gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.2.0

Comment: It appears you're on Ubuntu. I suspect that this is your problem and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061874/2166274

Comment: I don't have any project at the moment to use perf with, but as soon as I'll have to use it again, I'll try this out. Seems like it could work. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

When `perf report` gives you mangled names like `_Z*`, `_ZN*`, `_ZL*` etc, it means that your `perf` tool was compiled without access to demangling function or with it disabled. There is code to detect demangler in Makefiles:

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2.6/source/tools/perf/Makefile.perf

```
# Define NO_DEMANGLE if you do not want C++ symbol demangling.
# Define NO_LIBELF if you do not want libelf dependency (e.g. cross-builds)
```

http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2.6/source/tools/perf/config/Makefile

```
ifdef NO_LIBELF
...
  NO_DEMANGLE := 1
...
else
  ifeq ($(feature-libelf), 0)
    ifeq ($(feature-glibc), 1)
      LIBC_SUPPORT := 1
    endif
    ...
    ifeq ($(LIBC_SUPPORT),1)
      ...
      NO_DEMANGLE := 1
    ...
```

Tests are in the `tools/build/feature` directory: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2.6/source/tools/build/feature and libelf feature is enabled if test program using `elf_begin` function of libelf  ([`<libelf.h>` header of elfutils package](https://github.com/threatstack/elfutils/blob/master/libelf/libelf.h), `-lelf` linking) is available (and returns something? is there run test? what about cross-builds when kernel builder machine can't run target machine elf binaries directly with `./test-libelf.bin` and must use ssh to real machine or some user/system qemu?).

And the code in perf implementation to do demangling (using `cplus_demangle` if  HAVE_CPLUS_DEMANGLE_SUPPORT defined, using no demangle is NO_DEMANGLE is set after Makefiles, using bfd.h and `bfd_demangle` function [docs - 2.3.1.24 bfd_demangle](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.18/bfd/BFD-front-end.html)): 
http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.2.6/source/tools/perf/util/symbol-elf.c#L19

```
#ifdef HAVE_CPLUS_DEMANGLE_SUPPORT
extern char *cplus_demangle(const char *, int);

static inline char *bfd_demangle(void __maybe_unused *v, const char *c, int i)
{
    return cplus_demangle(c, i);
}
#else
#ifdef NO_DEMANGLE
static inline char *bfd_demangle(void __maybe_unused *v,
                 const char __maybe_unused *c,
                 int __maybe_unused i)
{
    return NULL;
}
#else
#define PACKAGE 'perf'
#include <bfd.h>
#endif
```

This all is bit strange (still no standard c++ demangle function in Linux world in post C++11 epoch?). And **your perf was miscompiled or misconfigured** - it is the reason why it does not demangle names. billyw [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34061874/2166274) by [Michal Fapso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1341914/michal-fapso) that says this is bug 1396654 of ubuntu - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1396654.

You may do hack of filtering output of perf with `c++filt` program but it prevent you from using interactive default TUI interface of perf (add `less` or write to text files to view very long listings with normal pageDown/pageUp):

```
perf report | c++filt | less
perf annotate function_name | c++filt | less
# or: perf annotate -s function_name | c++filt | less
```

Or you can update/recompile your perf as suggested by [billyw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166274/billyw) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34234354/perf-shows-mangled-function-names#comment59229697_34234354)

> 4^ It appears you're on Ubuntu. I suspect that this is your problem and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061874/2166274 – billyw Mar 3 '16 at 17:31